# dagre network - duplicated edges

Tags: cytoscape.js

when having a n-n relationship, is it possible to avoid the duplicated edges ? I am using the dagre layout:

```
 layout: {
          name: 'dagre',
          rankDir: 'LR'
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/me2p3ok9/

I would like a single edge connecting william to kate, then a single line going to george and charlotte, splitting in two. Here a picture for reference:

[image]

is this possible ?

Comment: "I would like a single edge connecting william to kate" there already a single edge

Comment: sorry, typed too fast. I meant a single edge between william, kate and their children. But see my answer, this should do the trick

Comment: still what you want is not clear. the updated jsfiddle shows a graph worse than the image in the question.  The image in the question has fewer edges.

Answer (score 0):

I found it : the taxi-direction has to be set in the same direction of the dagre (in my case rightward)

see updated fiddle. now the challenge will be to center the 3 nodes underneath